# React: TypeError: places.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, api-design

Trying to build a locations near you webpage with react and google maps api. So far I'm able to fetch the API data using rapidapi (Trailapi) based on my location using an axios get request. Ive currently stored the list of hiking trails in my state and passed them over to my List component. When trying to display my new list in my placedetails component it throws a TypeError: places.map is not a function. The data was changed to an array which can be passed into .map but I'm still getting an error that the data passed in isnt the correct type in my List.js file.

Sample Response (Output of data when scanning for simple locations near me)

```
{22965: {…}, 22972: {…}}
22965: {name: 'Coyote Hills Regional Park', city: 'Fremont', state: 'California', country: 'United States', description: 'Excellent trails.'}
22972: {name: 'Garin/Dry Creek Pioneer Regional Parks', city: 'Hayward', state: 'California', country: 'United States', description: 'The 20-mile system of trails within Garin and Dry …re suitable for bicycles. Please, no motorcycles.'}
```

index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getPlacesData = async (sw) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://trailapi-trailapi.p.rapidapi.com/activity/', 
          {
            params: {
              lat: sw.lat,
              limit: '10',
              lon: sw.lng,
              'q-state_cont': 'California',
              radius: '7',
              'q-activities_activity_type_name_eq': 'hiking'
            },
            headers: {
              'x-rapidapi-host': 'trailapi-trailapi.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': '19c3948709msh555b77273198f2ap102f38jsn78f1f9fd6b2e'
            }
          });
          console.log(data)
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {CssBaseline, Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import {getPlacesData} from '../api/index';
import List from './List/List';
import Map from './Map/Map';

function Browser() {
    const [places,setPlaces] = useState([]);

    const [coordinates,setCoordinates] = useState({});

    const [bounds,setBounds] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({coords: {latitude, longitude}}) => {
            setCoordinates({lat: latitude,lng: longitude});
        })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        getPlacesData(bounds.sw)
        .then((data) => {
            setPlaces(data);
        })
    }, [coordinates,bounds])

    return (
        <>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Grid container spacing={3} style={{width: '100%'}}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                    <List places = {places} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={4} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Map
                        setCoordinates={setCoordinates}
                        setBounds={setBounds}
                        coordinates={coordinates}
                        places={places}
                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Map.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import {Paper,Typography,useMediaQuery} from '@material-ui/core';
import LocationOnOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocationOnOutlined';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';

import useStyles from './mapstyles';

const Map = ({setCoordinates,setBounds,coordinates}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');


    return (
        <div className={classes.mapContainer} style={{height: '90%', width: '300%' }}>
            <GoogleMapReact 
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key:'AIzaSyDHTnVQEJGsaDcfMHdP2SGlJDixP83s9f8'}} 
                defaultCenter={coordinates} 
                center={coordinates}
                defaultZoom={14}
                margin= {[50,50,50,50]}
                options={''}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setCoordinates({lat:e.center.lat,lng:e.center.lng});
                    setBounds({ne: e.marginBounds.ne, sw: e.marginBounds.sw});
                }}
                onChildClick={''}
            >
                
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

List.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { CircularProgress, Grid, Typography, InputLabel, MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from '@material-ui/core';
import PlaceDetails from '../PlaceDetails/PlaceDetails';
import useStyles from './liststyles';

const List = ({places}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [type,setType] = useState('restaurants');
    const [rating,setRating] = useState('');

    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            <Typography variant='h4'>
                Trails all around you!
            </Typography>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel>Type</InputLabel>
                <Select value={type} onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}>
                    <MenuItem value="restaurants">Hiking</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="hotels"> Biking</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel>Rating</InputLabel>
                <Select value={rating} onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}>
                    <MenuItem value={0}>All</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={1}>1.0</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={2}>2.0</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={3}>3.0</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={4}>4.0</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={5}>5.0</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <Grid container spacing={3} className={classes.list}>
                {places?.map((place, i) => (
                    <Grid item key={i} xs={12}>
                        <PlaceDetails place={place}/>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
                
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}

export default List;
```

PlaceDetails.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const PlaceDetails = ({place}) => {    
    return (
        <h1> {place.name} </h1>
    );
}

export default PlaceDetails
```

And the accompanying style files

liststyles.js

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1), minWidth: 120, marginBottom: '30px',
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  loading: {
    height: '600px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    padding: '25px',
  },
  marginBottom: {
    marginBottom: '30px',
  },
  list: {
    height: '75vh', overflow: 'auto',
  },
}));
```

mapstyles.js

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles(() => ({
  paper: {
    padding: '10px', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100px',
  },
  mapContainer: {
    top: '1000px',
  },
  markerContainer: {
    position: 'absolute', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', zIndex: 1, '&:hover': { zIndex: 2 },
  },
  pointer: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
}));
```

Comment: What is the response value from `getPlacesData(bounds.sw)`? Is it still an array that is mappable?

Comment: The response value is no longer an array, and the object returned is a json nested object {key: {...}}. How would I go about solving both issues when passing it to my list component: Converting the object to an array and iterating through the nested obj using .map?

Comment: It kind of depends on what from the response object you are wanting to extract and render. Can you add a sample response to your question so we can see what its shape is?

Comment: Updated the following question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your initial `places` state is an empty array:

```
const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
```

But the response appears to be an object and you are subsequently updating into the `places` state and is passed to the `List` component to be mapped into the `PlaceDetails` component.

If no other component uses the `places` state then I suggest converting the response `data` into an array when setting the state. [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) can convert the object into an array of the object's values.

```js
const data = {
  22965: {
    name: 'Coyote Hills Regional Park',
    city: 'Fremont',
    state: 'California',
    country: 'United States',
    description: 'Excellent trails.'
  },
  22972: {
    name: 'Garin/Dry Creek Pioneer Regional Parks',
    city: 'Hayward',
    state: 'California',
    country: 'United States',
    description: 'The 20-mile system of trails within Garin and Dry …re suitable for bicycles. Please, no motorcycles.'
  },
};

console.log(Object.values(data));
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  getPlacesData(bounds.sw)
    .then((data) => {
      setPlaces(Object.values(data));
    })
}, [coordinates, bounds]);
```

The `places` state will be updated to an array of objects with the `name` property being rendered available.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Coyote Hills Regional Park", // *
    "city": "Fremont",
    "state": "California",
    "country": "United States",
    "description": "Excellent trails."
  },
  {
    "name": "Garin/Dry Creek Pioneer Regional Parks", // *
    "city": "Hayward",
    "state": "California",
    "country": "United States",
    "description": "The 20-mile system of trails within Garin and Dry …re suitable for bicycles. Please, no motorcycles."
  }
]
```

...

```
const PlaceDetails = ({ place }) => {    
  return (
    <h1>{place.name}</h1> // * 
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ensure that the `places` is an **Array** if you wish to use `map()`. It can be applied even to Array of Objects.

For example, in the snippet below, there's json data in `jsonResponse` that you want to filter the data based on their height. You can try inputting numbers and filter that.

```js
var jsonResponse = {
  status: "OK", 
  code: "200", 
  data: [
    {name: "Josh", height: 190},
    {name: "Mia", height: 185},
    {name: "Kevin", height: 180}
  ]};

function filterData(h) {
  var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  wrapper.html('');
  var result = jsonResponse?.data?.map((d, i) => d.height > h ? `<div id="${i}">${d.name}</div><br>` : '');
  wrapper.append(result);
}

$('#filter').click(e => {
  var h = $('#inputheight').val();
  filterData(h);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="height" id="inputheight" type="number" min="0" value="0"> 
<button id="filter">Filter</button>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```